# Getting error in transaction replace method

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I am creating a method for the Fragment transaction where i have to replace the container with the fragment.

```
 ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = ProfileActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.profile_fragment));
        transaction.commit();
```

The tutorial I am learning from is working fine but i am getting error i have checked with the import statements they are also the same what might be wrong?

```
Error:(48, 45) error: incompatible types: ProfileFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
```

Comment: Make sure your ProfileFragment class extends with Fragment from v4 package. If possible share profilefragment code here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = ProfileActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

put this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: @Vishal and you are 100% that all your imports are `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`? Also, check that in your `ProfieFragment` it extends the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, it has to be support version across all fragments